# Google gadget JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, google-gadget

My code is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Zombies!" height="350" />
  <Content type="html">
  <![CDATA[

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function load() {
   alert("test");
  }

  </script>
  <br />
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <input type=submit value="Next ->" onClick="load()">
  </div>
  ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
​
```

I am testing this code on

```
http://www.google.com/ig/modules/gadgetads.html
```

but when i add javascript code html is not showing . Please some one help me

Comment: http://www.google.com/ig/modules/gadgetads.html it's not available anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your code. The button with text "Next ->" is properly displayed.
There is no more HTML in your code snippet.

Comment: but its not displayed

Comment: I used your snippet and your link. I tried it in Firefox. What browser did you try?

Comment: When you go on the test page, select all within the editor window and delete the prewritten text, then insert your snippet, then hit the Preview tab.